# How to take snapshot from given region of the screen with python?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ocr

Here is my thoughts:
1) snap shot the given region from the screen like (100,100,80,60), save the result as image
2) process the image with OpenCV python interface

Just be first to python and wonder if this is good solution,be specific,wonder how to snapshot with python.

Thanks,

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple using `CGRectMake` in Apple's `CoreGraphics` api:

```
CG.CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)
```

This allows you to define the horizontal/vertical positions, and width/height respectively.

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Quartz
import LaunchServices
from Cocoa import NSURL
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG

def screenshot(path, dpi, region = None):

    if region is None:
        region = CG.CGRectInfinite

    image = CG.CGWindowListCreateImage(
        region,
        CG.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
        CG.kCGNullWindowID,
        CG.kCGWindowImageDefault)

    url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(path)

    dest = Quartz.CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(
        url,
        LaunchServices.kUTTypePNG, 1, None
        )
    prop = {
        Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: dpi,
        Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: dpi,
        }

    Quartz.CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image, prop)
    Quartz.CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)

spec = (0, 0, 800, 600) # x, y, w, h
path = '/path/to/screnshot_region.png' # save path
area = CG.CGRectMake(*spec) # set area to cgrect

screenshot(path, dpi=72, region=area) # call function
```

To use, just call the function:

```
screenshot(path, dpi=72, region=area)
```

*`dpi` will set the image output resolution; leave out the `region` argument for fullscreen capture. In regards to the `OpenCV` portion - I don't use it often enough to provide anything at this time.